# Android. How can I get the parameter that come from Listener onSuceess

Tags: android

```
public List<Post> loadPostsFromBomb(){

        postList = new ArrayList<>();

        BmobQuery<Post> query = new BmobQuery<>();

        query.findObjects(ContextHolder.getContext(), new FindListener<Post>() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Post> object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (object.size() != 0) {
                    postList.addAll(object);
                    Toast.makeText(ContextHolder.getContext(),postList.get(0).getUserName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ContextHolder.getContext(),"还没有约球组织",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int code, String msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(ContextHolder.getContext(), msg + " " + code, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return postList;

    }
```

The BmobQuery is a kind of Bass tool. Now, I can get the  object in the onSuccess() right, and the postList in onSuccess can be Assignment right.But when return the postList, it is null.

What's the problem? I think it maybe is the Listener's problem.. How can I get the object in the onSuccess method? Thanks a lot about your attention.

Comment: object is the what you get in Onsucess() it's a List . what happening with your code can you please elaborate?? aren't you able to access the object parameter

Comment: loadPostsFromBomb() method runs on main thread and  query.findObjects runs on different thread. when query.findObjects thread call the onSuccess that only it comes back to main thread (Here onSuccess is call back). what happened in your code query.findObjects is just call and return empty list. you need to process after onSuccess called.

Comment: Do you mean that I must handle the data in the method onSuccess?

Comment: I can get the object parameter rightly, and I want to pass it to another variable, so I can use it in other Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this way:

Add interface:

```
public interface ResponseListener {
    void onSuccess(List<Post> objects);
}
```

Create `method` instead of `function`:

```
public void loadPostsFromBomb(ResponseListener listener){

    postList = new ArrayList<>();

    BmobQuery<Post> query = new BmobQuery<>();

    query.findObjects(ContextHolder.getContext(), new FindListener<Post>() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Post> object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (object.size() != 0) {
                postList.addAll(object);
                listener.onSuccess(postList);
                Toast.makeText(ContextHolder.getContext(),postList.get(0).getUserName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ContextHolder.getContext(),"还没有约球组织",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int code, String msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(ContextHolder.getContext(), msg + " " + code, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
 }
```

You need to implement ResponseListener in `Activity`/`Fragment`:

You would receive List on `Override` method.

```
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ResponseListener  {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_menu);

  // Other stuff

  loadPostsFromBomb(this);

  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(List<Post> objects); {
   Log.i("List" , "Received");
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this, in the activity, the onSuccess get receive right data. But now, what I want is use the queried data as the data source of a Recycleview. So, the data I queried must pass to the RecycleviewAdapter. Is there any method that let me get the queried data into another variable ,that I can use it anywhere?

Comment: @htxf, yes you can use RecyclerAdapter and pass your List with constructor, and if your problem is resolved as your question, please mark as accept to avoid duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

It will always return null, because your return statement get called before

```
 public void onSuccess(List<Post> object)
```

so instead of return create a global List. So that you can access it after **onSuccess()**  function

Comment: Can I make the return method executed after the onSuccess() method?

Comment: yes create another method which return `List` and call this from onSuccess()